# IShellWindows error with IE10 and plain C

Tags: python, c, com

I am developing a mouse event listener with plain C and python based on library called Pyhook. I am doing some adjustments in that library in order to retrieve information about the UI element which was clicked by the user.

I am using the interface UI Automation to retrieve information about the elements which were clicked by user. However, when I want to retrieve an element inside a Webside, this interface does not allow me to do that as far as I know. That is why I decided to validate if the current window is Internet explorer and then if I retrieve the object of IE, I could create a listener inside the DOM.

The issue comes when I want to retrieve the Internet Explorer object. The issue is when I am moving the mouse over the Internet Explorer window, the mouse is delayed and it does not move faster inside the content of the webside. I have a long code but I decided to summarize a little bit what I have. My impression is when I create the interface pShellWindows. Maybe I could not use CoCreateInstance many times. Someone could help me with my objective. If you need more detailed, I am happy to share more. Tks in advance.

```
LRESULT CALLBACK cLLMouseCallback(int code, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

...

IUIAutomation *pAutomation = NULL;
IUIAutomationElement *element = NULL;

CoInitialize(NULL);
...
HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_CUIAutomation,NULL,CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,&IID_IUIAutomation,(void**)&pAutomation);
...

  if(wcsstr(process_name,IEName)!=NULL){

    IShellWindows *pShellWindows = NULL;
    ...
    HRESULT hr = CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_ShellWindows,NULL,CLSCTX_ALL,&IDD_IShellWindows, (void**)&pShellWindows);
    ...
    IUnknown_Release(pShellWindows);
  }

...

CoUninitialize();

} 

int cSetHook(int idHook, PyObject *pyfunc){

HINSTANCE hMod;

if(idHook > WH_MAX || idHook < WH_MIN){
  pyErr_SetString(PyExc_ValueError, "Hooking error: invalid hook ID";
}

Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
hMod = GetModuleHandle(NULL);
if(NULL==hMod)
  hMod = GetModuleHandle("_cpyHook.pyd");
Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS

switch(idHook){
  case WH_MOUSE_LL:
    if(callback_funcs[idHook]!=NULL)
      break;
    callback_funcs[idHook] = pyfunc;
    Py_INCREF(callback_funcs[idHook]);
    
    Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS
    hHooks[idHook] = setWindowsEx(WH_MOUSE_LL,cLLMouseCallback,(HINSTANCE) hMod,0);
    Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS
    break;
 case WH_KEYBOARD_LL:
  ...
}

if(!hHooks[idHook]){
  PyErr_SetString(PyExc_TypeError, "Could not set hook");
}

return 1;
}
```

**EDIT:**
After checking the code I realized that the problem is when I want to release the object pShellWindows. I do not know why I got this issue. Maybe the events occurs so fast and the system cannot release the object and system requires some delay to do it?.
**EDIT2:**
I added more information about how the cLLMouseCallback is called. As far as I understood, the `Py_BEGIN_ALLOW_THREADS` macro opens a new block and declares a hidden local variable; the `Py_END_ALLOW_THREADS` macro closes the block. I was wondering if these macros affect the way to use IShellWindows. Forgive me if I am writing something fool but I tried many things to use IShellWindows and I have not achieved it.

Comment: IShellWindows has nothing to do with IUIAutomation, you can call CoCreateInstance as many times as you want, I don't understand your question. Do you get errors back?

Comment: @SimonMourier Tks for your time reading my post. My objective is to retrieve info about the element clicked by the user when user clicks on a button on a website (For example the button search on Amazon). When I run my code to listen the events, and I move mouse over the website using Internet Explorer, seems that mouse cannot move properly and it stops for some seconds. I was thinking that maybe when I move the mouse I create this interface and it delayed the speed of the mouse.

Comment: In general UI Automation does not impact the automated app (in reality this can happen in rare cases but I don't think this is the case here). You can automation IE using UIA but you shouldn't need IShellWindows.

Comment: Tks I thought I could not extract info of element which belongs to the DOM with UIAutomation. Using IUIAutomationelement, it always returns me the whole internet explorer window instead of a button in the DOM for example. Do you know how I should do it?.

Comment: Use "Inspect.exe" tool from Windows SDK. It will definitely show you what you can get from UIA. If something doesn't show up in inspect, it's probably not possible. It's very well possible that you cannot get a DOM element from UIA. In this case head to other technologies such as selenium.

Comment: @SimonMourier  I tried to use Selenium but it doesn't allow me to connect to the existing opened browser. Do you know maybe another library with plain C to add an event listener into the DOM in order to see which element was clicked by the user?

Comment: The only way would be to write a BHO (only for IE) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_Helper_Object. They run in process with IE so you can hook events, but the user must approve it before it can run.